# How to make eclipse plugin view always appear on right with fixed size

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am new to eclipse plugin development. With the given sample of "Plugin with a view", the view is creating successfully. But this view can be made to move at any corner and the size of it keeps on changing. How could i make it to appear always on right with a fixed width & height.

Comment: I don't know of any way to make a view a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to use a Perspective for this, at least that is what I've done in my plugin.

Create a perspective implementing `IPerspectiveFactory` (extension point `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions`) and you can design an initial layout defining where a view opens as well as its width/hight.

You can use this [link](http://eclipsepluginsite.com/perspectives.html) as a rough guide.